# Not able to get unique list for particular column in React-table using filters

Tags: reactjs

> ```
> export class FruitShopPage extends Component {
>             return (
>                 <div>
>                     <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Fruit Shop</Button>
>                     <Modal isOpen={this.state.collapse} size="lg">
>                         <ModalHeader>Fruit shop</ModalHeader>
>                         <ModalBody>
>                             <div className="form-group">
>                                 <div>
>                                     <ReactTable
>                                         data={this.state.listFruitsData}
>                                         columns={columns}
>                                         defaultPageSize={10}
>                                         getTrProps={onRowClick}
>                                     />
>                                 </div>
>                                 <div>
>                                     <Row>
>                                             <Button type="submit" onClick= 
>                                              {this.toggle}>Buy</Button>
>
>                                     </Row>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </ModalBody>
>                     </Modal>
>                 </div>
>             )
>       }
> }
> ```

- I am using React Table where I am populating data(listFruitsData) from post request
- eg)listFruitData contains key-value pair fruitCode:'1234'
- Now suppose there are many records with same fruitcode(1234) many times
- when I add filter code its shows data but it shows all records with fruitcode 1234 I wanted that in react-table it should show unique list not repeated data.
- below is my code for filtering data

> ```
> <Select
>     onChange={entry => {
>         this.setState({ selectFruitcode: entry });
>         if (entry === null) {
>             this.onFilteredChangeCustom('', 'fruitCode');
>         } else {
>             this.onFilteredChangeCustom(
>                 entry.map(o => {
>                     return o.value;
>                 }),
>                 'fruitCode',
>             );
>         }
>     }}
>     value={this.state.selectFruitcode}
>     options={this.state.listFruitData.map((o, i) => {
>         return {
>             id: i,
>             value: o.fruitCode,
>             label: o.fruitCode,
>         };
>     })}
>     isMulti
>     name="fruitCode"
>     className="basic-multi-select"
>     classNamePrefix="select"
> />
>
> onFilteredChangeCustom = (value, accessor) => {
>         let filtered = this.state.filtered;
>         let insertNewFilter = 1;
>         if (filtered.length) {
>             filtered.forEach((filter, i) => {
>                 if (filter['id'] === accessor) {
>                     if (value === '' || !value.length) filtered.splice(i, 1);
>                     else filter['value'] = value;
>                     insertNewFilter = 0;
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>         if (insertNewFilter) {
>             filtered.push({ id: accessor, value: value });
>         }
>         this.setState({ filtered: filtered });
>     };
> ```

Comment: Can you post the code for onFilteredChangeCustom. Looks like that's the code that does the filtering. If you want to get only one array result that matches a specific condition you can use Array.prototype.find instead of  Array.prototype.filter. probably that might be the issue.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: sure,have added code for FilteredChangeCustom ,please do let me know if you require anymore details